# jQuery: add and remove contents to another div

Tags: php, jquery

Is there any jQuery & PHP tutorial available which is having functionalities like:

1. Add or remove contents from one tab to another.
2. Save those in sessions.

Please have a look at [this website](http://myfav.es/settings/sites/#/all-sites/).

Looking for the same functionalities.

Comment: tab mean ? Jquery tabs or browser tabs

Comment: using jquery session plugin you can do that all stuff https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin

Comment: @kuldeep raj. Tab means something similar like this webpage http://myfav.es/settings/sites/#/all-sites/

Answer (score 0):

[session plugin](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin)
using that plugin you can save your value in to session

```
// To Store
$(function() {
    $.session.set("myVar", "value");
});


// To Read
$(function() {
    alert($.session.get("myVar"));
});
```

and using normal jQuery you can add and remove will be done like

For add

```
$("#orherdiv").html($('#someotherdiv).html());
```

and for Reomve

```
 $("#orherdiv").html('');
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply softdev... are you having any tutorial using that session plugin ? coz i'm not so good in jquery

Comment: sorry i don't have it
follow steps as mention on plugins documents